# Does “We're going to buy you X” sound vaguely confrontational, vs. “We’ll buy you X”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, will-be-going

[McWhorter, J](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter),  [*Our Magnificent Bastard Tongue* (2009)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Our-Magnificent-Bastard-Tongue-History/dp/1592404944), [p 127.](http://publicism.info/history/bastard/4.html)
[emboldening mine]

> What they think brings English back to par with German and the rest is, for example, the tricky English future tense. Future tense marking in English is a highly subtle affair, much more so than in other Germanic languages. Could you explain what the difference in meaning is between *I will go, I’m going to go, and I’m going*? They are not just interchangeable ways of expressing futurity. Try this: you tell someone that you’ve always wanted a pair of argyle socks and they say, “Okay, tomorrow we’ll buy you some.” Now, imagine if they said instead, “Okay, tomorrow we’re going to buy you some.” **Notice how that second sentence has a different meaning—it sounds vaguely confrontational. Nobody taught you that—it’s a subtlety of English grammar.** It’s hard, this English future—I am so thankful I learned it from the cradle. A non-native speaker I knew whose English was truly spectacular once said when I asked her age, “I turn twenty-five.” Mmm, not quite. It has to be “I’m turning twenty-five.” Only if you started with a time expression could you use the bare

p 128

> verb: “Tomorrow I turn twenty-five.” Subtle—or, to a non-native, hard.

Can someone please expound the emboldened sentence, and help me understand this subtlety? The  [*going-to* future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future) doesn't feel 'vaguely confrontational' to me at all.

Comment: I don't agree with the author at all. Either about that sentence or about the statement at the end discussing how an expression of age *must* be phrased.

Comment: The *turning twenty-five* example rings true. The allusion to a vague confrontation probably turns on the author's own history with the phrase. It's possible to read it that way, but it's also possible to read it differently.

Comment: What "vaguely"? "... going to ..." has a menacing tone, if not an implication.

Comment: _Going to buy_ sounds more definite to me, but not “vaguely confrontational.”

Comment: It depends on context and intonation, anything can sound menacing or confrontational if you accompany the words with a scowl on your face. A partner or parent *might* select the "going to" form over "will" if they felt exasperated, they could add stress the word *we're* or *buy* to emphasise their mild irritation. It's very subjective.

Comment: @KarlG Yes. I believe you are right. It wouldn't, for example, be "menacing" to say - "I'm going to buy you an ice-cream". But as you point out "I am going to..." carries a more determined intention. And that could be determinedly menacing "I'm going to throttle you", or determinedly enchanting "I'm going to kiss you in the moonlight".

Comment: These judgements seem very subjective, and probably are based on the immediate speech community in which one acquires the language. I must say I agree with most people here in that I cannot see any confrontation in the _going to_ future either.

Comment: I think the difference relies on pragmatics. In the first a different kind of promise is offered through the modal "will" as opposed to the direct "are". This is about being decisive and being direct with one's words as to not make a false promise as with "will" whereas "are" as karlg says is more definitive. Consider: 1) He (will be) a teacher 2) He (is going to be) a teacher and 3) He (is) a teacher. (2) may be more "confrontational" than (1) as it's more direct, it does not sugar coat words in the sense that you either are going to be a teacher  or not (as opposed to will).

Comment: The difference is lost because it's talking about a future tense action: "We will buy" and "We are going to buy" as seen in (1) and (2): but (3) highlights the subtle difference of will vs are in (1) and (2). Being indirect may also be considered more polite than being direct in some contexts.

Comment: “Okay, tomorrow we’re going to buy you some” can be said in a way that's full of promise and considerateness. “Okay, tomorrow we’ll buy you some” can sound very dismissive. It seems to be a subtlety of English grammar too far for some.

Comment: You can say absolutely anything with absolutely any amount of confrontation. You can call someone a cunt as a term of endearment, and they will actually take it in that spirit, too. Or could tell them they are a hero, and they will understand that what you really did is call them a cunt. It's not that the author is imagining things that are not there; it's that he's wrong about where that "there" actually is. It's in the language alright. Not in the grammar, though.

Comment: Sorry to be so blunt and at the evel of the passage, that is pure rubbish. At a very different level, involving hours or pages of argument, there might be some differences to be justified but how many hours do you have, please? Broadly, it comes back to rubbish, unjustified and unjustifiable.